# How do I know their favorite food?

Tags: yo-kai-watch

When Whisper describes making friends with Yo-Kai, he tells me that I can increase my chances by feeding them their favorite foods during battle. I've been trying to make friends with a Leadoni, but I can't find listed anywhere what types of food it likes.

Is there some way to figure out what food it likes? If I throw random food at Yo-Kai, will the game tell me if I get it right?

Answer (score 1):

yes. when you give a yo-kai its fave food hearts appear on top of it. you can also make it easier to befriend yo-kai by pinning a wisp. if it comes out as a heart you get all enemies to have hearts on top of them.